# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application '{project_name}.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module

Tags: django, heroku, wsgi

I can't understand why I'm facing an error while running Heroku run `python manage.py runserver`

I tried changing folder names and I tried removing and adding `WhiteNoise` in `MIDDLEWARE`

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    # 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]
```

## database settings

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

### wsgi.py

```py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ss.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

at least the server should run so that I can see whats the issue with Heroku.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [**`documentation`**](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html), middleware configuration should be like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

And you can remove the whitenoise related lines from wsgi file as well:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
#  from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ss.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
#  application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Because in [**`whitenoise >= 4.0`**](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0), you don't need to change in wsgi file.

Comment: @rudra im actually trying to host this applciation in heroku trying to figure why am i getting this error

Comment: probably this line is throwing error `from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise`, because it does not exist anylonger

Comment: yeah will try that now ,but that is important to host the application heroku right ?

Comment: whitenoise is responsible for serving static files, if you don't need to serve js/css/img(static files) then you can omit it for now.

Comment: yes its working perfectly fine ,but now i need to serve static files as well please can you tell me what should i do

Comment: Heroku has a detailed documentation on this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Answer (score 0):

Your `wsgi.py` file is incorrect.

`os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '{{PROJECT}}.settings')`

The code above is the issue, you need to replace `{{  project }}` with your actual app name.

It's the folder name where the `settings.py` is located.

For example, if this is your project structure.

```
blog
      ...
    - settings.py
    - wsgi.py
      ...
```

Then the correct code is `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'blog.settings')`

Comment: i just mentioned {{project}} as an example

Comment: Why didn't you mention that? please update your code to show all the settings.py and full traceback as well as the correct project name